# ReactJS: Handsontable Cell Data Clearing after Rerender

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

Im implementing Handsontable (https://handsontable.com/docs/) into one of my projects however im encountering an issue where when my button `onClick` function fires, it causes a rerender and all the cell data that was inserted into the Handsontable becomes deleted.

```js
<HotTable
  ref={hotTableComponent2}
  data={[]}
  colHeaders={['Case ID', 'Name']}
  rowHeaders={true}
  width="100%"
  columnHeaderHeight={35}
  rowHeights={30}
  manualColumnResize={true}
  persistentState={true}
  stretchH="all"
  minSpareRows={1}
  licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation"
/>
```

```js
<Button onClick={() => SubmitFunction()}>Submit</Button>
```

Any ideas on how to prevent the table from deleting the cell data on rerender?

TIA

**EDIT**

After further investigation, it seems that the button state `(setButtonLoading(true))` that fires in the `SubmitFunction()` is responsible for deleting data captured in the HandsonTable.

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-neumann-08euk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example, e.g. on codesandbox?

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets apologies about that. I definitely should've included a demo link. Please see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-neumann-08euk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets I have also updated my post with more information on my findings

Comment: @Vega please explain why the demo is unusable? I believe it depicts the issue that im facing clearly

Comment: Ah, now it works, before there were bunch of uninstalled libraries, making the demo un-runnable. But, is the demo code the same as in the post?

Comment: @ayushlal achieved any success? As it seems to me, there should be a method that would bind the data to the table and also the changes in the table to the data. But for now I have not found it and now have a feeling that there is only this `data` field, that initializes the table and that's it. Have you tried writing to the support?

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets I did manage to find another way to capture all of the data after cell change. Just need some more time and will push that change to ```state``` and the table data will point to the state which should hopefully resolve this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are editing the cells, you are not saving them in state and passing blank array in data object in table props. When it rerender it has only blank array.

What to do?
You need to create a state and save data that you enter in column in that state. So it will be saved and pass that in your data prop. Now if it will rerender the data will be fetched from state variable.

Instead of  `data={[]}` you should pass  `data={stateVariable}`

Comment: I understand however capturing the data into state is another issue I don't really know how to tackle. The documentation isn't really helping either

Comment: @ayushlal Check this https://handsontable.com/docs/cell-editor/#overview

Comment: I still cannot find anything pointing towards capturing the data within state...